# Apply customized function for extracting numbers from string to multiple columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataset as follows:

```
   id name   value1   value2 value3
0   1   gz        1        6     st
1   2   sz  7-tower  aka 278      3
2   3   wh      NaN       67   s6.1
3   4   sh       x3       45     34
```

I'd like to write a customized function to extract numbers from `value`s columns.

Here is the pseudocode I have written:

```
def extract_nums(row):
    return row.str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=True)

df[['value1', 'value2', 'value3']] = df[['value1', 'value2', 'value3']].apply(extract_nums)
```

It raise an error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Code for manipulating columns one by one works, but not concise:

```
df['value1'] = df['value1'].str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=True)
df['value2'] = df['value2'].str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=True)
df['value3'] = df['value3'].str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=True)
```

How could write the code correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `filter` the `value` like columns then `stack` the columns and use `str.extract` to extract the numbers followed by `unstack` to reshape:

```
c = df.filter(like='value').columns
df[c] = df[c].stack().str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=False).unstack()
```

Alternatively you can try `str.extract` with `apply`:

```
c = df.filter(like='value').columns
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda s: s.str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=False))
```

Result:

```
   id name value1 value2 value3
0   1   gz      1      6    NaN
1   2   sz      7    278      3
2   3   wh    NaN     67    6.1
3   4   sh      3     45     34
```

Comment: Please note in there is a string `st` in `value3`, btw, could you also filter by setting column names?

Comment: @ahbon Its was due to `update`..edited the answer.

Comment: So it's not necessary to write a function `extract_nums(row)` then apply to `df[cols]` as in the question?

Comment: You can write the seperate function `extract_nums` and apply to `df[cols]` but its technically same as using a `lambda`  function inline with `apply`. If you would like to use `extract_nums` just make sure to set the parameter `expand=False`.

Comment: Could you help to correct the function in the question?

Comment: Sure..Check [`here`](https://repl.it/@ShubhamSharma13/SarcasticPreemptiveIntroductory)

Answer (score 3):

The following code also works out:

```
cols = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=True)
```

Alternative solution with function:

```
def extract_nums(row):
    return row.str.extract('(\d*\.?\d+)', expand=False)

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(extract_nums)
```

Out:

```
   id name value1 value2 value3
0   1   gz      1      6    NaN
1   2   sz      7    278      3
2   3   wh    NaN     67    6.1
3   4   sh      3     45     34
```